How should this kalimba be tuned?

I found this kalimba (thumb piano) at the school where I teach.  At least, that's what I think it's called.  It isn't very authentic or well built (made in China).
It sounds awful.  I'd like to tune it but have no idea what to tune it to.  Some bars are painted blue.  Any ideas?

It took exactly one Google search for me to find the answer.

@Aaron - but now, kalimba tuning is included in the repertoire of this site!

I have a kalimba that looks very similar to this one with the note names marked on it.
The middle note is C, and then the notes form a major scale alternating left and right. So going left from the center: C D F A C E G E D, going right from the center C E G B D F A C E.
The blue paint only seems to help with your orientation.

I have a similar instrument. Centre (longest) tine is C. Then going right, it's marked E G B D F A C E. Going left, it's D F A C E G B D. These letter names must be correct (for mine) as there are numbers corresponding to scale places as well as those letter names.
Tuned by knocking the tines gently until in tune (I used piano).
I also managed to fit a pick-up to it, so it's now an electric kalimba!
It would have made more sense to colour all the C notes blue, but it's pretty random.

I have no way of knowing whether the blue was from the factory or added later.
